# Passing Child Classes of a Base Class to a constructor using CRTP?

Tags: c++, crtp

I have the following Base Class:

```
class BaseVisitor
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseVisitor() {};
};

template <class T>
class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(T&) = 0;
};

template <class Visitable>
class Expression
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    void accept(T& visitor)
    {
        visitor.visit(static_cast<Visitable&>(*this));
    }
    void print() {
        static_cast<Visitable*>(this)->print();
    }
    void eval() {
        static_cast<Visitable*>(this)->eval();
    }

};
```

And the Classes that inherits from Expression:

```
class Literal : public Expression<Literal>
{

protected:
    int value = 0;
public:

    Literal() {};
    Literal(int x);
    std::string print();

    int eval();
};

class Add : public Expression<Add>
{
protected:
    Literal lhs;
    Literal rhs;

public:

    Add(Literal left, Literal  right);
    void print();
    int eval();
};
```

I want to be able to pass an Expression to Add constructor, so I can be able to call `Add(Add(Literal(10),Literal(20)),Literal(30)).eval()` resulting in 50. 
Is this possible in C++11?

Comment: Yes, it's possible in C++, but complicated. The search term you are looking for is [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) (this article lists some examples at the bottom you could study).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you make `Add` a template instead of hard-coding that its left and right arguments must be Literals:

```
template<typename L, typename R>
class Add : public Expression<Add<L,R>>
{
protected:
    L lhs;
    R rhs;

public:

    Add(L left, R  right) : lhs(left), rhs(right) {}
    int eval() { return lhs.eval() + rhs.eval(); }
};
```

Compiling `Add(Add(Literal(10),Literal(20)),Literal(30)).eval()` then requires C++17.  If you want to make it work with C++11 you need to write a wrapper function analogous to `std::make_pair` to avoid having to write `Add<Literal, Literal>` and so on.